# How does "salary savings" typically work?

Tags: funding, salary

For each grant I write, I ask for summer salary. This is usually about a month of pay. Since I'm on a 9 month contract, this means that I can fill in three months of salary from grants. In the unlikely circumstance that I will be awarded more than three grants (and hence, more than three months of salary), what happens to the remaining salary?

I have heard of "salary savings" programs at American universities, how does that work? Is this just a separate fund that I can pull from in the future for summer salary? Is there a university "tax" on this money, where they keep a portion of it?

Comment: Check the rules for whatever grants you're applying for, but in the cases I'm familiar with, the granting agencies wouldn't allow you to take more than three months of summer salary.

Comment: My university doesn't allow me to be paid for more than 12 months per year, so with my 9-month contract, I can use at most three months of summer salary. But the National Science Foundation has generally been very good about approving no-cost time extensions of grants. So that unspent money can be spent (for the same purpose) after the original grant period has ended. Other granting agencies and other universities may have entirely different policies.

Comment: I believe overhead is charged on all non-capital expenses, so yes there is a "tax".

Comment: As a general rule, the NSF won't approve of more than 2 months of summer salary per year, so you'll need to get grants from other agencies.  Once you've filled up the summer, the typical next step is "buying out of courses" to reduce your teaching load during the academic year so you can do more research.

Comment: I see. Thank you all for your comments. I submit to both DOD and NSF to seek full summer funding. I figure most agencies wouldn’t let me fund more than 3 months, but I was just wondering about the off chance that they would all get funded at once. I suppose teaching buyouts would be the answer.